# The meaning of proffer

Tags: meaning, verbs

I have encountered the word **proffer** a few times and most of these times I find the word to be completely interchangeable with **offer**.

When and why is this word used? Am I misunderstanding the word?

Google translate supports my interchangeability position, so I'm not native speaking.

Edit: The proposition that proffer is built as (pre-)offer (as in first), is not at all appealing to me as a non-first offer would be a counter-offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proffer is an initial (first) offer, or one made at the start of negotiation. There are additional, legal senses of the word (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proffer), but that is the distinction I would make for ordinary usage.

[Also](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/offer) "implies voluntary action motivated especially by courtesy or generosity", as in (thanks to @horatio)

> proffer an apology

Comment: Wikipedia makes the distinction: "The act of proffering involves making an offer prior to any formal negotiations" . Merriam-Webster does not make this distinction. The M-W Learner section defines **proffer** as to **offer**  so I'm not any more enlightened. Edited first post.

Comment: Check the synonyms at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/offer for more clarification, @CaptainGiraffe. I took my common meaning as a combination of the way I have heard it used, and the pro- prefix meaning "before in time or position". I didn't include the sense of "implies voluntary action motivated especially by courtesy or generosity", but will add that.

Comment: @captaingiraffe: in ordinary conversation if one were to "proffer an apology," the apology might have been offered and delivered before it was demanded. Whereas one would not proffer an apology in response to a demand. Note that proffer is fairly uncommon in my personal experience and, as such, the distinction might not be fully apprehended or appreciated.

Comment: @horatio fairly uncommon, as in: not so uncommon, yes. Your example deserves to be an answer. It seems this word is not easily defined by description, but rather by example.

Comment: The courtesy/generosity argument seems to me quite strong. I appreciate that.

Comment: @horatios example very much supports this too.

Comment: Sorry to add to the question, but the pronunciation I would expect to be **pr** + **offer** ?

Comment: I think that the example really only serves to illustrate what JeffSahol has posted. In that respect, my comment is not an answer at all. I would not be averse to JaffSahol lifting the example and placing into his answer.

Comment: You mean you are proffering it, @horatio?

Comment: Yes, that would be satisfactory. Is **proffer** considered stiff upper lip btw? lol Jeff

Comment: Good idea to explain why "proffer an apology" is a good example. Now I just need to work it in to my vocabulary =/

Answer (score 0):

The object, to my mind, would have to have some tangible quality, typically involving a negotiation.  One can proffer a settlement, but offer an opinion.

Comment: It is well possible to proffer advice or assistance, both non-tangible, as a [first hit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proffer) on google readily tells you.